# How to select last record from each day with MySQL

Tags: mysql, max

I know there are already some solutions to this question but they don't seem to be working for me.

I want to select the last record from each day, per user, on my database. I have a database that stores a user's location by country and date down to the second.

The select query I'm trying to run is:

```
SELECT MAX(date), id, country FROM dk_location_records WHERE userid = '10'
AND (date > '2012-04-06 00:00:00' AND date < '2012-05-08 23:59:59')
AND active = '1' GROUP BY DATE(date) ORDER BY date ASC
```

However, what this actually does is show me the last date from each day, but not the correctly corresponding `id` and `country`. It actually gets the first `id` and `country`, alongside the last `date`.

What am I doing wrong?

Help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Can there be several records with the same timestamp for a given user?

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't want lots of records per user, just the last entry per user.  Basically "where was user X last". Several answers below seem to be mis-understanding.

Comment: Devart's solution is what I was after. I wanted the last entry from each day for any given user. So for user with ID 10, I want to know their location at the end of each day since the 6 April. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this query to show last record from each day, per user, -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM dk_location_records t1
  JOIN (SELECT DATE(date) date_date, userid, MAX(date) max_date
        FROM dk_location_records
        GROUP BY date_date, userid
        ) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.max_date AND t1.userid = t2.userid;
```

...add your WHERE conditions if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not group by `DATE(date)`. I think you should group by `userid,country`. Like this:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(date), userid, country 
FROM 
  dk_location_records 
WHERE 
  userid = '10'
  AND (date > '2012-04-06 00:00:00' AND date < '2012-05-08 23:59:59')
  AND active = '1' 
GROUP BY userid,country  
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

You should get the correct results by changing your ORDER BY to DESC instead of ASC

Comment: That's what I thought initially, unfortunately it doesn't make any difference, same problem persists.